# I'm unable to vertically center <h2> in a <div> tag

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I've got a problem with centering  in another tag .
I have no problem with horizontal align in a flexox or in a old fashion way but vertical is still  a problem for me.

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;    
    width: 130px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    
}
h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The flex properties like justify content and align items has to be on div not h2. Placing on h2 will make the items inside it to be aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. The `h2` element is not in a flex container (you have to set `display: flex` on the parent `div`)
2. The properties `justify-content` and `align-content` have to be set on the flex container, not the flex item.
3. For centering a flex item vertically in a flex container with `flex-direction: row`, you have to use `align-items` rather than `align-content`

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;    
    width: 130px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;    
}

h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Headline 2</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `div` should have:

```
div {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to make the **Children Div** **vertically** Centered, is to make the display of the **Mother div** **Flex**, **not** the **Children div**.

```css
div {
    display: inline-flex;
    background-color: green;    
    width: 130px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}
h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h2>hello</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree 100% with the answers display flex on container not child.

Even if I'm always using flex, and css grid, I would like to add another solution "old fashion" way based on line-height:

```css
        div {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: green;
            width: 130px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            line-height: 45px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 100;
            line-height: 45px;
        }
```